# Communicating connection state between clients

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the iOS app I'm making, I want one user to know immediately if another user lost connection to the Firebase database. The onDisconnect method would work if it were not for the fact that it does not fire immediately, but instead fires after a few minutes have elapsed. Is there anything I'm missing in the API, or perhaps some clever (and not too messy) workaround that can accomplish this?

Constant communication between these two users is very important, so it's critical that one knows immediately if the other has lost their ability to communicate.

Comment: Calls to firebase are asynchronous, so they will take there own time.But what you can do is ensure a good network connection. Or are you asking how to communicate like code and all?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out a way for user A who is connected to the database to know if user B is or is not connected to the database, and to know quickly if user B's connection has changed (has come online or gone offline). Maybe some kind of virtual handshake would work.

Comment: @Dravidian Please do not add bad English to titles. Also, do not add technologies like "Firebase,Swift" to the title - that's what tags are for.

Comment: @LeoNatan Duly Noted.. :)

Answer (score 1):

To check if a user has gone offline or online to your Firebase Database you can :-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(".info/connected").observe(.value,with : {(Snap) in 

  let connected = Snap.value as? Bool 
  print(connected!)  


})
```

**`.observe(.value, with : ...`** will open a separate network thread which will get called whenever the user's state is changed.

There are two possibilities :-

- User deliberately closes the app.

  Just add this to your Data Structure :-

  ```
    online_Users: {

      userID1 : true,
      userID2 : false,  // user 2 went offline
      userID3 : true,
      userID4 : true,
       ....
       }
  ```

And whenever your user goes offline or online just change this status to respective `false` or `true` by checking through **`connected!`** in above code block. Most probably you have to take into account the possibilities of app going into **background**, **terminating** etc.., whose call blocks are generally present in the **`AppDelegate`** such as *`func applicationWillResignActive(_:`*, *`func applicationDidEnterBackground(_`* . Just surf through the documentation

Then retrieve your user2 active state in your user1 app and there you go. Infact listen to the **childChanged** from your user1 app for user2 state that way it will be triggered every time it changes.

- User losses its network connection, as suggested by @Frank in comments:-

  ```
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("online_Users").onDisconnectUpdateChildValues([FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid : false], withCompletionBlock: {(Err, Ref) in


      print(Ref)
      print(Err?.localizedDescription)


  })
  ```

Also see :- [Firebase Documentation For offline capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence)

**PS:-** Mathematically there can be four possible ***combination's*** to this particular situation. Any user state be either `true` or `false` so mahtematicaly speaking its (2C1)*(2C1) = 4. But i think you get the jist. To make your app foolproof you would need to satisfy all four of those combinations.

Comment: I know how to handle everything you just mentioned except for what to do if and when the user losses their network connection. Since the user will not have been able to tell the database they were disconnecting, I don't know how another user can see that they just got disconnected. What do you mean by manipulate the security rules?

Comment: You'd do that by using `onDisconnect()`. It allows you to specify a write operation that the database server does when it detects that the client has disconnected. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your input.

Comment: Doesn't onDisconnect() have a lag time if the network connection drops? If the user simply quits the app then onDisconnect works immediately, but if the internet just drops out then onDisconnect will only work once the database is sure that the user is not connected which can be a few minutes. For my purposes lag is bad.